# Style injection Javascript event

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

Styleinjection in Livereload, Codekit, Mixture etc. is cool!
But is there a way to listen for it in Javascript?

I want to run a js function whenever new CSS is injected.

Comment: maybe investigate the pub/sub patterns, through jquery or other frameworks.  you can write your own, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the style is inserted in the HEAD tag, you could use MutationObservers to listen for any changes to the DOM and filter out unneded ones. 
You could listen on the entire document, but performance can degrade quickly, so if you can get away with listening on the HEAD element, it would be best.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

You could build a wrapper, like this:

```
$.fn.cssEvent = function (what, value) {
  $(this).css(what, value).trigger('styleChanged', [what, value]);
};

$('.element').cssEvent('color', 'black');
```

I realize now that I totally misunderstood the question...